# Graphical bash does not run after removing python

Tags: 18.04, bash, desktop-environments

On `Ubuntu 18.04`, I uninstalled `python*` which led to uninstallation of `ubuntu-desktop` and many other apps. I installed `python3.8` and then `ubuntu-desktop`.

Now I can run command line on `ctrl+alt+F3` but I cannot run it under graphical environment. I also tried

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~
```

Followed by logging again and it didn't help.

I also do not know the name of the graphical bash to try reinstalling.

What should I do?

---

Note: I also set `python3.8` as alternative for `python`. Not sure that makes problem.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 2
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

And still having problem.

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to [gnome-terminal](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/introduction.html.en)

Comment: @steeldriver, thanks. I checked `gnome-terminal` is installed. Any idea?

Comment: Ubuntu relies heavily on python, so by removing python the tools that require it to function need to also be removed.  The tools also are built for a specific version of python, so if that version isn't available, you'll find they **may** no longer run (tools such as `gnome-terminal` requires the python it was built for; what came with your release; that was what it was tested to run with; if your system doesn't have that version - it may not run, or may not run correctly).   https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/gnome-terminal

Comment: @karel, no, it doesn't

Answer (score -4, accepted):

it was fixed after

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

and pointing to `python3.6` instead of `python3.8`.

By the way,

```
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal
```

has a head that starts with

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Nothing to do with `python2`.

Still not clear what is the cause.

---

**Update**:

You do not need to change the default python version.

Just run

```
sudo nano '/usr/bin/gnome-terminal'
```

and change the header to:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
```

Done.

Just ensure on the next software update, it is not overwritten.

Comment: Do not touch system python and files which are controlled by APT, they will be overwritten on next package update. Spreading such methods is dangerous and is not useful.

Comment: @ar2015 nor do you have the right to counter in an unfriendly tone.

Comment: @ThomasWard, what part of the answer is unfriendly?

Comment: @ar2015 I never said the answer was unfriendly.  Your comments, however, in their tone, were unfriendly.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu relies heavily on `python`, so by removing python the tools that require it to function need to also be removed.

The tools also are built for a specific version of python, so if that version isn't available, you'll find they **may** no longer run (tools such as `gnome-terminal` requires the python it was built for; what came with your release; that was what it was tested to run with; if your system doesn't have that version - it **may** not run, or may not run correctly).

https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/gnome-terminal

Comment: I'd expect problems when you make changes with the default `python` (*which means python3` for modern releases*) unless you're careful and do it properly.  Those problems are fixed by restoring things back to what they should be (*or doing it correctly*).  Do your homework before touching python3 on Ubuntu.